# Visual Studio 2008 (C#) Not Reflecting Changes Made to the Form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2008, controls

Currently making a form application in C# using Visual Studio 2008. 
I have MainForm.cs[Design] file with many buttons, labels, and panels on it, and I had been using it for a while with no problem. Then, I had to add a new button on the form, which I did. However, the change on the form seems not to be reflected. 
The button does seem to exist on [Design] file. 
I did the followings:

1) Double clicked on the button, which led me to the inside of MainForm.cs, and created button_Click method for it. I even added code inside it.

2) Checked MainForm.Designer.cs file and I found the information for the button I just added.

3) Checked buttonAdded.Visible to be true.

4) Closed and re-opened Visual Studio.

5) Moved the button around the form to see if it might have been hidden underneath other controls, but found out that it was not the case.

However, I still don't see the button added when I run the project.

Can anyone please help me reflect the change on the form? Thanks!

Comment: does the button exist under any container (like, panel, groupbox, splitter, etc)? If so, whether the Visible property of that control is true?

Comment: Yes, there is a panel below the newly-added button, and the panel's visibility is true as it keeps showing it when the program is running. I also found out that any other changes are not reflected either. I have moved a label within the panel, but when I run the program, the result is showing the label at the original position.

Comment: Sorry, but the Button is inside any panel/ container, or it is completely independent in UI?

Comment: I just realized something. It is not just the newly added button that is not reflected. I moved a label around, but when I run the program, the label is shown on the original location. Also, I commented out some code, but that code is still getting executed. It seems like it is running the old program from before I made all those changes...

Comment: Crystal ball says that you did not see the compiler error message.  In which case it will *still* run the program, but it will be the previously compiled version.  Always the first thing I change in a new VS install: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "... out of date" = Always build and "...error occurs" = Do not launch.

Comment: I changed the settings but it is still running the old program. I even rebooted my computer still to no avail.